# Silverlight IsMouseOver not working

Tags: xaml, silverlight

I ran into following problem as below. It is not working and I cannot work out what I may be doing wrong.

```
<Polygon Name="Polygon1" Points="0,0 40,0 20,20" Opacity="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,-10" Fill="#FF547E80">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOverState">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Polygon1"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                     To="1"
                                     Duration="00:00:00" />
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Polygon>
```

Answer (score 1):

Visual states can only be applied to objects that derive from `Control`.  The framework controls that support visual states are the heavier, more complex elements like Button.  Polygon is derived from the lower-level FrameworkElement.

Polygon does support the mouse events `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave`, so you might want to just subclass it and add the appropriate event handlers.  Or you could wrap a Polygon in your own Control and trigger the whatever visual state changes yourself.